# How to calculate the Poisson integration?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

When solving Laplacian equation, I need to integrate the following integration:

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1+3\text{sin}\theta}{a^2+r^2-2ar\text{cos}(\theta-\phi)}\text{d}\theta
$$

How to work it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that,

$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1+3\text{sin}\theta}{a^2+r^2-2ar\text{cos}(\theta-\phi)}\text{d}\theta= \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1+3\text{sin}\theta}{a^2+r^2-2ar\,({\cos}(\theta)\cos(\phi)+\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi))}\text{d}\theta \,.$$

You can use residue theorem to evaluate the above integral using the [technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211058/evaluating-frac12-pi-int-02-pi-frac11-2t-cos-theta-t2d-theta/211068#211068). Also, you can find more detials about the technique [here, see example(III)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration).

Comment: I think that the observation $$ a^2 + r^2 - 2ar\cos(\theta-\phi) = \left|ae^{i\phi} - z\right|^2 = (ae^{i\phi} - z)(ae^{-i\phi} - \bar{z})$$ for $z = re^{i\theta}$ will also help apply residue theorem.

Comment: That's beautiful method, thank you!

Comment: @hxhxhx88: You are welcome.