# Evaluate$ \ \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin^2 \theta}{5 + 4 \cos \theta}\,d \theta \ $ using contour integration and the calculus of residues

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, trigonometry

Evaluate$
\
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin^2 \theta}{5 + 4 \cos \theta}\,d \theta 
\
$ using contour integration and the calculus of residues

Comment: Here is a related [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211058/evaluating-frac12-pi-int-02-pi-frac11-2t-cos-theta-t2d-theta/211068#211068).

Comment: This is your third problem in a very little while. The way you ask questions is not considered polite in this site. Please refer to FAQ about this, and *anyway*: it'd be refreshing and nice to see some self work, ideas from you on these problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2\theta}{5+4\cos\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061705/evaluate-int-02-pi-frac-sin2-theta54-cos-theta-mathrm-d-theta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $z=e^{i\theta}$ so that you're integrating counter-clockwise around the unit circle in the complex plane. Express your integrand in terms of $z$, using
$$\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}\right),$$
etc. Then it should be a straightforward residue problem.

Comment: $$\sin\theta=\frac{i}{2}\left(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}\right),$$ And then plug cos and sin into the integrand?

Comment: Or, do I just switch the sin2 theta into 1-cos2 theta and work from there?

Comment: either way works, though the formula you wrote for $\sin\theta$ is off by an overall minus sign.