# Complex Fourier series

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, definite-integrals, fourier-series

I need to find the complex Fourier series of this function, and I'm having problems  calculating these integers:

$$|a|<1$$

$$x\in [-\pi,\pi]$$

$$f(x)=\frac{1-a\cos(x)}{1-2a\cos(x)+a^2}$$

$$a_0=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1-a\cos(x)}{1-2a\cos(x)+a^2}dx$$

$$b_n=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1-a\cos(x)}{1-2a\cos(x)+a^2}\sin(nx)dx$$

Comment: Thanks! I'm Tring to learn latex to post it right!

Comment: It would also be useful if you give the original function as well.

Comment: I tried to answer but I cannot keep up with all the edits that ask a different question every few minutes...

Comment: To evaluate the integrals, you can use the [following technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211058/evaluating-frac12-pi-int-02-pi-frac11-2t-cos-theta-t2d-theta/211068#211068) from complex variables.

Comment: By the way, where did this problem come from?

Comment: @Amccds: By the way, do not worry about the down votes. It is just misleading people.

Comment: I dont worry about it...

Answer (score 4):

> Note: The following answers the question before it was edited and changed.

Let $z = e^{ix}$ (so $|z|=1$) then

$$
f(x) = \frac{1-a^2}{(1-a z)(1-a z^{-1})} = \frac{a}{z-a} + \frac{1}{1- a z}.
$$

As a function of $z$ this has the following Laurent expansion on the unit circle:

$$
\frac{a}{z}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^k}{z^k} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a^k z^k = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a^k(z^k + z^{-k}) = 1 + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a^k \cos(k x)
$$

This gives the Fouries series of $f$ without calculating any integral.

---

> The same can be done for the latest form of $f$.

$$
f(x) = \frac{2-a (z + z^{-1})}{2(1-a z)(1 - a z^{-1})} = \frac{a}{2 (z-a)}+\frac{1}{2 (1 - a z)}+\frac{1}{2}
$$

The Fourier series is now apparent given the previous result:

$$
f(x) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a^k \cos(k x)
$$

Comment: That's pretty cool but I don't understand how you did it...

Comment: What is the Laurent expansion of this. $$ f(x) = \frac{2-a (z + z^{-1})}{2(1-a z)(1 - a z^{-1})} = \frac{a}{2 (z-a)}+\frac{1}{2 (1 - a z)}+\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @Amccds Do you know the geometric series? Since $|z|=1$ and $|a|<1$ that suffices to expand this function as Laurent (power) series in $z$.

Comment: I'm asking as you told me to the first exercise, to get the fourier complex serie...

Comment: @winC can you please do the Laurent expansion on the unit circle like you did for the first case so then we get to the complex fourier serie?

Comment: @Amccds Divide the first series by $2$ and add $\tfrac{1}{2}$ to get the second series.

Comment: @WinC The right result my book says the sum should start from 0 , the second result should be "0+sum from 0 too..."

Comment: Solved thanks a lot

Comment: Wow using the unit circle like that.