# expansion of $\text{ cosh}(z+1/z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

It is given that if $|z|>0$, 
$$\text{cosh}(z+1/z) = c_0 + c_1 (z + 1/z) + c_2(z^2 + 1/z^2) + \dots $$
where 
$$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \cos (n \phi) \text{cosh}(2\cos \phi ) d\phi$$

I only know to expand $\text{cosh(z + 1/z)}$ by putting $w = z + 1/z$ and expand it as $\frac 12 (e^{w} + e^{-w})$. How do I introduce $c_n$, any hints?

ADDED:

Here's what I got
$$c_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{\text{cosh}(z+1/z)}{z^{n+1}}dz = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \text{cosh}(2\cos \phi)e^{-in \phi}d\phi$$

It seems that $c_n = c_{-n}$ by the symmetricity of $z+1/z$ and of $\cos(-z) = \cos(z)$ but how to get rid of the imaginary part above?

Comment: And what is wrong or terrible with writing down the expansion of $\,\cosh z\,$ by using the very well known and nice expansion of the exponential function?

Comment: @DonAntonio i don't know, the exercise say so, maybe I should look into $c_n$ from Laurent theorem.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374274/complex-fourier-series/374332#374332).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write $z=e^{i\phi}$, then $\cosh(z+1/z)=\cosh(2\cos\phi)=f(\phi)$ is an even $2\pi$-periodic function of $\phi$ which can therefore be expanded into Fourier cosine series:
$$ f(\phi)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos n\phi,\tag{1}$$
with
$$ a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(\phi)\cos n\phi\,d\phi.$$
These $a_n$'s are related to your $c_n$'s by $a_n=2c_n$ (note that $z^n+z^{-n}=2\cos n\phi$).

---

Addendum: Fourier series can be seen as the restriction of Laurent series to the unit circle. Note, however, that once you know coefficients of the former, this also gives the coefficients of the latter.

Comment: could you elaborate the last?? what is the relation between Fourier series and Laurent series?

Comment: I've added a small comment. Is it ok now?

Comment: thank you ... it is very interesting which i did not know. but before that could you check some of my thoughts? I have added in question.

Comment: Concerning imaginary part: the function you integrate is periodic and you integrate over one period. Therefore instead of going from $0$ to $2\pi$ you could go from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. But the imaginary part is an odd function of $\phi$, so the corresponding integral is equal to $0$.

Comment: Hmm ... i see, thank you very much!!