# find $\int_0^{\pi} dx/(a \cos^2x+b \sin^2x)^2=?$

Tags: integration

I know that : $$\int_0^{2\pi} dx/(a^2 \cos^2x+b^2 \sin^2x)^2=2\pi/ab$$

now : 
$$\int_0^{\pi} dx/(a \cos^2x+b \sin^2x)^2=?$$

my try:I do not know where to start.:(

thank you very much !

Comment: Try dividing and multiplying by $b \cos^2( x)$.

Comment: An excellent answer has already been posted here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455147/closed-form-of-int-02-pi-fracdxa2-cos2xb2-sin2xn

Comment: @bacon might you give me a hand and mark this question as duplicate?

Comment: @tired, sure how do I  do so?

Comment: @bacon click 'close' (below the main body of the question) and choose the option 'duplicate'

Comment: @tired - ok no poblem :-)