# Definite integration of $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln(a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x)dx$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What would be the best way to approach the integral

\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln(a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x)dx
\end{equation*}

I've tried imitating the method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455147/closed-form-of-int-02-pi-fracdxa2-cos2xb2-sin2xn?rq=1) to no avail. Would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried taking partials with $a$ and $b$, looks pretty promising, not sure though.

Comment: I haven't tried it and I'm unfamiliar with the method! Is that method differentiating under the integral sign?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking, in-capturing  some  information about the partial derivatives, then using that for $f(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln(a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x)dx$ we have $f(1,1)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume $a, b > 0$.

If your integral is $f(a,b)$, then $f(b,b) = \pi \ln b$ and 
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial a} = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2 a \sin^2 x}{a^2 \sin^2 x + b^2 \cos^2 x}\; dx = \frac{\pi}{a+b}$$
Conclude
$$ f(a,b) = \pi \ln((a+b)/2) $$